# PHPUnit 5.7: Mock file_get_contents

Tags: php, phpunit

I have this code:

```
if (is_null($contenu)) {
    if (file_exists($filePath)) {
        $contenu = file_get_contents($filePath);
    } else {
        throw new \Oft\Mvc\Exception\NotFoundException('Fichier inexisant');
    }
}
```

I wantto mock the **file_get_contents** function

Answer (score 2):

Use https://github.com/mikey179/vfsStream in your tests. This library will let you mock most filesystem operations, including `file_get_contents()`.

Answer (score -1):

Why can't you just create a variable containing the mocked file contents?